$P[a - 1 < X < a + 1]$ is maximized.

Let $ X$ be a random variable with a normal distribution $ N(\mu,
\sigma^2) $. Find $a$ such that $P[a - 1 < X < a + 1]$ is maximized.

I am tasked with finding $a$ such that $P[a - 1 < X < a + 1] $ is maximized, where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.
The probability I was asked to maximize is:
$$
P[a - 1 < X < a + 1] = P\left(\frac{a - 1 - \mu}{\sigma} < Z < \frac{a + 1 - \mu}{\sigma}\right)
$$
where $Z$ is the standard normal variable $Z \sim N(0,1) $.
I want to maximize the probability that $X$ lies in the interval $(a - 1, a + 1) $. Could someone help me to continue this idea or have better way to deal with this problem?

Due to Symmetry , Maxima is at $a=\mu$ , nothing more.

A careful argument: We seek to maximize over $a\in {\mathbb R}$ the function
$$H(a):=\int_{a-1}^{a+1} f(x)\,dx$$ where $$f(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left\{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$$ is the density of the $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and the chain rule to compute
$$H'(a)=f(a+1)-f(a-1).$$ To obtain the critical points of $H$, solve the equation $H'(a^*)=0$, obtaining the equation
$$\exp\left\{-\frac{(a^*+1-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}=\exp\left\{-\frac{(a^*-1-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right\}$$ which is the same as the equation
$$(a^*+1-\mu)^2=(a^*-1-\mu)^2.$$
The only solution to this last equation is $a^*=\mu$. To confirm that $H(a)$ achieves a maximum at $a=a^*$, check that the second derivative $H''(a^*)$ is negative.
